# Flat table with identity values

Tags: r, reshape

I have this tidy data frame:

```
mydf <- expand.grid(
  A = letters[1:3],
  B = letters[4:5],
  C = letters[6:7], 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
mydf$D = runif(nrow(mydf))
```

I would like to make it a flat table like with `myft <- ftable(mydf, row.vars = 1, col.vars = 2:3)`, but instead of having a contingency table, I would like the corresponding values of column `D`.

I tried using `myft[] <- mydf$D`, this is better but the values are not in the good order. How can I match the same order (i.e. the value of `D` that corresponds to the values of parameters `A`, `B` and `C`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myarray <- xtabs(D ~ A + B + C, data = mydf)
ftable(myarray, row.vars = 1, col.vars = 2:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question specifically asks for an `ftable`, but you may find it more direct to simply work with some of the more common functions that are used for reshaping data.

Here, for example is `dcast` from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
dcast(as.data.table(mydf), A ~ ..., value.var = "D")
##    A       d_f       d_g       e_f        e_g
## 1: a 0.2655087 0.9446753 0.9082078 0.06178627
## 2: b 0.3721239 0.6607978 0.2016819 0.20597457
## 3: c 0.5728534 0.6291140 0.8983897 0.17655675
```

Here's the "tidyverse" approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
  unite(var, B, C) %>% 
  spread(var, D)
##   A       d_f       d_g       e_f        e_g
## 1 a 0.2655087 0.9446753 0.9082078 0.06178627
## 2 b 0.3721239 0.6607978 0.2016819 0.20597457
## 3 c 0.5728534 0.6291140 0.8983897 0.17655675
```

---

I recommend this simply because these formats would be easier to index and reference by predictable column names. In an `ftable`, you actually don't have `dimnames` but "col.vars" and "row.vars", which aren't as convenient to access. Because of that, you can't do things like `data.frame(myft)` or even `as.data.frame.matrix(myft)` and maintain the shape of your reshaped table.

---

To answer your question about how to match the order of the variables when you tried `myft[] <- ...`, you can try the following:

- Reorder the values of "D" according to the factor columns (A, B, and C) in this case.
- Convert that to a row-wise matrix. You should be able to easily calculate the number of rows required from the data.
- Use that matrix as the replacement values.

Example:

```
myft[] <- matrix(mydf$D[with(mydf, do.call(order, list(A, B, C)))], 
                 nrow = length(unique(mydf$A)), byrow = TRUE)
myft
#   B          d                     e           
#   C          f          g          f          g
# A                                              
# a   0.26550866 0.94467527 0.90820779 0.06178627
# b   0.37212390 0.66079779 0.20168193 0.20597457
# c   0.57285336 0.62911404 0.89838968 0.17655675
```

Comment: I'm quite happy with the solution of Nathan. But thanks for this other answer

Comment: @F.Privé, no problem! I've always found the lack of `dimnames` with an `ftable` to be a bit frustrating, so I just thought I would suggest some alternatives.